# Generated RPM has requirement on files it contains but doesn't provide them

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to create an RPM from libraries that have been built externally.

My spec is basically this:

```
Name:     ace-tao
Version:  6.5.3
Release:  1
Summary:  ACE and TAO libraries
License:  other
Vendor:   My Corp
Group:    Applications/Engineering
Packager: My Corp <info@example.com>
Prefix:   /usr/local/foo

%description
Contains the ACE and TAO libraries.

%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/%{prefix}/lib
cp -f %{_sourcedir}/deps/libACE*.so.%{version} %{buildroot}/%{prefix}/lib/
cp -f %{_sourcedir}/deps/libTAO*.so.2.5.3 %{buildroot}/%{prefix}/lib/
(
  cd %{buildroot}/%{prefix}/lib/
  for lib in libTAO*.so.2.5.3; do
    ln -s $lib ${lib%.3}
    ln -s $lib ${lib%.5.3}
    ln -s $lib ${lib%.2.5.3}
  done
)

%files
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%{prefix}
```

The TAO library has the requirement that there be symlinks `libTAO*.so`, `libTAO*.so.2` and `libTAO*.so.2.5` to `libTAO*.so.2.5.3`, hence the `ln` calls.

After I build this with `rpmbuild -bb ace-tao.spec`, I get a file `ace-tao-6.5.3-1.x86_64.rpm`. However, installing this yields warnings:

```
15:16:32,868 WARN packaging: ace-tao-6.5.3-1.x86_64 requires libTAO.so.2.5.3()(64bit)
15:16:32,868 WARN packaging: ace-tao-6.5.3-1.x86_64 requires libTAO_CodecFactory.so.2.5.3()(64bit)
15:16:32,868 WARN packaging: ace-tao-6.5.3-1.x86_64 requires libTAO_10RTable.so.2.5.3()(64bit)
... snip ...
```

Checking the requirements of the package with `rpm -qRp ace-tao-6.5.3-1.x86_64.rpm` indeed lists

```
libTAO.so.2.5.3()(64bit)
libTAO_AnyTypeCode.so.2.5.3()(64bit)
libTAO_CodecFactory.so.2.5.3()(64bit)
... snip ...
```

The RPM doesn't provide them though:

```
$ rpm --provides -qp ace-tao-6.5.3-1.x86_64.rpm
ace-tao = 6.5.3-1
ace-tao(x86-64) = 6.5.3-1
```

Even though it contains them:

```
$ rpm -qlp ace-tao-6.5.3-1.x86_64.rpm | grep TAO
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO.so
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO.so.2
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO.so.2.5
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO.so.2.5.3
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_AnyTypeCode.so
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_AnyTypeCode.so.2
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_AnyTypeCode.so.2.5
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_AnyTypeCode.so.2.5.3
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_CodecFactory.so
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_CodecFactory.so.2
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_CodecFactory.so.2.5
/usr/local/foo/lib/libTAO_CodecFactory.so.2.5.3
... snip ...
```

Why is that? What do I need to change for the RPM to provide the libraries it contains?

I am on CentOS 7.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for RPM's automatic dependencies system to pick up shared objects, they need to have their executable bit set.<sup>[1]</sup> I suspect you are not doing that here.

So in your `%install` section, either use `install -Dm 755` instead of `cp`, or `chmod 755` them. Note that you only need to do this for regular files; symlinks have mode `777` by default.

And although not ideal, you can always declare `Provides:` entries manually as a last resort.

---

P.s. I'm not sure if autodetect will work when you install to non-standard paths (i.e. outside of `%{_libdir}`). If setting the executable bit didn't work, you may wish to try installing to `%{buildroot}%{_libdir}` instead.

<sup>[1]</sup> I did search through RPM's source code, but didn't find any explicit documentation of this behaviour. The relevant source code seems to be `rpmfc.c` FYI.

Comment: Thank you, setting the executable bit indeed fixed it. Thankfully the non-standard path isn't an issue, since this is not something I can currently change.